# Traducción de "verbatim"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

¿Existe algún término en español que signifique lo mismo que "verbatim" en inglés? Google Translate sugiere un anglicismo que [no existe en el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/significe?m=form).

Comment: Un comentario: cuidado con ‘que una palabra no exista en el DLE’. Hay muchísimas palabras que existen y que no están registradas en *ese* diccionario. En este caso tu planteo es más que lícito, pero hay muchos diccionarios y herramientas a disposición de las que uno puede valerse para consultar. Asimismo, el traductor de google no es el único que existe

Comment: Otro comentario: ahora busqué la palabra en el traductor de Google y la traduce bien, creo que pifiaste cuando escribiste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción que más recomiendo es **literalmente**, es una palabra bastante versátil que suele servir para la mayoría de las ocasiones y es la que más la encontré en lenguaje escrito y oral. Otras posibilidades serían las locuciones **palabra por palabra**, **línea por línea** o **textualmente** (esta última no la recomiendo tanto porque podría prestarse a ambigüedades en algunos casos); todas son completamente válidas.

> —Did you finished your work?  
> —Yes, I copied the text **verbatim**.

> —¿Terminaste tu tarea? 
> —Sí, copié el texto **al pie de la letra**.

Uy, cierto que también se me olvidó esta última y hermosa expresión que mencioné, y que solemos usar cuando queremos resaltar la capacidad de alguien para retener, memorizar o ejecutar algo tal como fue pedido. Suele verse en general con la expresión *hacer al pie de la letra* o con *seguir las instrucciones al pie de la letra* u otro verbo que implique ejecutar una acción más que con el sentido de ‘copiar un texto’, pero también es válido darle este uso a la expresión.

En cambio, las cuatro primeras voces mencionadas tienen una connotación neutra o negativa. Dato de color: aquellas mismas también podrían emplearse como el antónimo de *metafóricamente*, recordemos que esto último se dice cuando uno es capaz de interpretar un texto por fuera de lo que el mismo expresa directamente; es decir al encontrar ‘algo más’ que simplemente el recurrir a la mera definición de cada palabra. Pero de todas formas creo que estás prguntando por la otra acepción—transcribir un texto tal cual se lo recibe.

En suma, si estás buscando una connotación positiva o resaltar lo que sucedió como algo bueno entonces podés usar *al pie de la letra*. En cualquier otro caso usá *literalmente*, *palabra por palabra*, *línea por línea* o *textualmente*.